# NodeJS Express - How to retrieve list of socketio rooms from controller

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have a socket.io server in my `app.js` file

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = https.createServer(options, app);
const io = require('socket.io');
const ios = io(server);

const routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', routes);
```

from that file, I know how to get the list of rooms

```
ios.sockets.adapter.rooms
```

Now I need to access `ios` from one of my routes file (in which I also implement "controller" logic, I will refactor later)

```
# routes/index.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    //
    // I'd like to check ios.sockets.adapter.rooms HERE
    // HOW DO I DO THAT?
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way, maybe no the best way to do it.
You need to pass **io** instance to your router. I use a **wrapper** function.

```
//router.js
const router = express.Router();

const wrapper = function(io){
   //work with your router
   router.get('/endpoint',(req,res) => {

   });
});

export default wrapper;
------------------------------------

//server.js
import yourRouter from "./yourRouter";
//socket
const server = http.createServer(app);  
const io = socket(server);

//express
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//here you can pass the instance
app.use(yourRouter(io));
```

Another way using **middleware**

```
//server.js
// middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.io = io;
    next();
});

app.use(yourRouter);

//router.js
import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/payments/cancel', (req, res) => {    
     //get the instance
     const io = req.io;     
     res.send('Ok');    
});
export default router;
```

The second one is cleaner, and don't need a wrapper function.

Comment: well appreciated. I went for the middleware option. I now also understand how to use middleware! Cheers mate.